# How can I check in Thymeleaf if a spring bean exists

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am writting a Thymeleaf template that would get some data from a spring bean. My project is using spring-boot (if it matters). There are situations when a certain bean is not available. How can I check inside the template if a bean exists or not ?

I tried like checking a variable, but it doesn't work

```
<div th:if="${@myBean != null}" th:text="Bean exists"></div>
```

I get a

> NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'myBean' available

Comment: You could set an indicator to your model

Comment: I've searched, I can't seem to find a way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
${#objects.nullSafe(obj,default)}
```

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#objects

and easier, you can check bean exist in Spring's Controller.

Comment: Just as I feared, the same exception is thrown as probably the `nullSafe()` method does nothing more than a null comparison, just as I did (see question). For documentation porpouses, what I came up with is `${#objects.nullSafe(@myBean, @existingBean).someMethod()}`